# Is Docker global service always created first on new Swarm node?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

In Docker Swarm Mode (1.12+) it is possible to create so-called 'global' service, eg:

```
docker service create \
 --name redis_2 \
 --mode global \
 redis:3.0.6
```

Global service is active on each node.

What is the order of service creation when I add a new node to Swarm and when Swarm has some pending services to create?

Does Swarm *guarantee* that global service is created **first** (until its healthcheck passes), and only after that Swarm creates pending replicated services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no guaranteed order in which services are started. Best practice is to design your applications / services to be resilient against failures of other services. Keep in mind that services can be interrupted at any time during your application's lifecycle (services are updated, networks can be temporarily unavailable, nodes or even data centers can go down).

If a service depends on another service, you can (for example) implement a retry-loop; a simple example can be found in the official WordPress image, which has a retry loop to check if the database server is available, and accepting connections; https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/637afb53dc03b4af19149a0880e796346f97c137/php5.6/apache/docker-entrypoint.sh#L170-L181

Comment: What you said is definitely true for replicated services, and I am aware of that. However, this is not dependency between services I am talking about. I haven't got impression that this also applies to _global_ services. Do you know maybe any official Docker doc that mention global services in regard of execution order?

Comment: Other than "where" global services are deployed (i.e., one per node, unless a `--constraint` is added), "global" services are not treated any different from "replicated" services (see [Replicated and global services](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/how-swarm-mode-works/services/#/replicated-and-global-services))